# object is probably 'undefined' - Mocha

Tags: protractor, mocha.js

I am using Protractor. The below solution works, but i get this warning:

`this.currentTest.state`
- error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' 
(property) Mocha.Context.currentTest?: Mocha.Test | undefined

How do i fix this warning?

Test file:

```
const helper = new HelperClass();
  afterEach(async ()=> {
    const state = this.currentTest.state;
    await helper.getSource(state);
});
```

Class File

```
import { browser, } from 'protractor';
export class HelperClass {

    public getSource(state:any) {

        if (state === 'failed') {
            browser.driver.getPageSource().then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurs because the access to `this.currentTest.state` happens inside another function: the arrow function passed in to `afterEach`--flow analysis does not cross function boundaries.  Try simply pulling that line outside of the function:

```
const helper = new HelperClass();
  afterEach(async ()=> {
  const state = this.!currentTest.state;
    await helper.getSource(state);
});
```

Does that change anything?

Comment: if i put it outside of the function, i get: Property 'currentTest' does not exist on type 'Suite'. If i put it outside of the describe i get: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation'.

Comment: Um..... Try this:


`const helper = new HelperClass();
      afterEach(async ()=> {
        await helper.getSource(state);
              const state = this.!currentTest.state;

    });`

Comment: I edited my answer because the comment was unreadable.  Basically I'm trying to tell it 'yeah, this is undefined, so what'? To avoid the warning and move on.

Comment: no, it didnt work. I got `Multiple variable declarations in the same statement are forbiddents `.

Comment: But i seem to have solved it by adding this: any in the function 
 `afterEach(function (this: any) {
        const state = this.currentTest.state;
        helper.getSource(state)`